# SDL without a window (Windows service)

Tags: windows, service, window, sdl

I need to use SDL in windows as part of an application that is a service.

The application basis is just to take a screenshot of a 3D file opened with SDL, and is working well out of the box.

The problem is that SDL_Init complains when the application is started in windows' services context.

> No displays available

I know that if I don't use a window I will not have inputs from keyboard and mouse, anyway I don't need them for my app.

Is there any way to have SDL offscreen on windows ? I heard about mesa/osmesa, but it seems it's only on Linux

Comment: How are you going to take a screenshot from a service. Your service runs in a session 0 and cannot see the desktops in any of the interactive sessions.

Comment: The screenshot is taken by the SDL app, by using the glReadPixels() method. But i can adapt it if i get an offscreen buffer, representing the pixels of the view

Comment: So you have a process on the desktop that takes the screenshot, and you want to send that to the service process that then processes the image. Correct?

Comment: Ah no sorry I didn't explain it well. I will edit my post, but i just want to take a screenshot of my application, that mean, i open an OBJ file, and generate a thumbnail from it.

Comment: You cannot readily do that from a service. You need a process running on that desktop to do it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think this is doable with an offscreen rendering library, like OSMesa.

Comment: @Warren How will this defeat session/desktop isolation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It has nothing to do with process isolation. The window to capture is spawned by the service process. It captures itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that this can be done via changing your service properties and maybe some tricks with the Windows registry. I have not tried but this post and the comments to it may be useful: https://lostechies.com/keithdahlby/2011/08/13/allowing-a-windows-service-to-interact-with-desktop-without-localsystem/. Here is a MSDN entry on the subject (see "Using an Interactive Service" section): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. Though at least the MSDN article looks to address the question in the view of service interaction with the users via GUI that is related but a bit different thing that the service interaction with graphics.

Once I came across an application which was using SDL and failed to initialize itself properly when started from the service. Setting the environment variable SDL_VIDEODRIVER to 'dummy' helped me than. The graphics functions of the application look to be  working OK with this setting (though I am very unsure whether this will be enough for your use case involving opening of a 3D file).